# How to make TurboGears treat '%2F' differently from '/' when routing?

Tags: python, url-routing, turbogears2, turbogears

I have a simple TurboGears 2 script, named app.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from wsgiref.simple_server import make_server
from tg import expose, TGController, AppConfig

class RootController(TGController):
    @expose()
    def lookup(self, name):
        return name

config = AppConfig(minimal=True, root_controller=RootController())

print("Serving on port 5000...")
httpd = make_server('', 5000, config.make_wsgi_app())
httpd.serve_forever()
```

When I run app.py and visit http://localhost:5000/lookup/dave, I see "dave" as expected. But when I visit http://localhost:5000/lookup/dave%2Fdavid, I get a 404 error instead of "dave/david". It seems that TurboGears is splitting 'dave%2Fdavid' into two separate arguments.

How can I get TurboGears to respect that an escaped slash is different from an unescaped slash?

Comment: Web browsers definitely distinguish between / and %2F.

Comment: There was a TurboGears bug report about this 10 years ago and it was "fixed" (but now it's back): http://trac.turbogears.org/ticket/377

Comment: Upon further research, you seem to be correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to distinguish `/` from `%2F` in standard WSGI applications. There was [a long argument about this in 2008](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/web-sig/2008-January/003127.html), but the WSGI spec authors decided that compatibility with CGI--which does not distinguish between the two either--was more important than letting the programmer decide how to interpret a `%2F`.

In the end I decided to convert `/` to `%252F` when building paths, and then run `replace('%2F', '/')` on every variable I get from the path. This is not a very elegant solution, but unless the WSGI authors have a change of heart I don't see a better option.

Comment: Actually it seems to me that the Section 4.1.5 of CGI RFC https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-coar-cgi-v11-03 (to which WSGI 3333 points to) explicitly says that `PATH_INFO` is not url encoded: `"Unlike a URI path, the PATH_INFO is not URL-encoded"`.

Answer (score -1):

For your specific example you can probably work-around that by adding `*args` to your lookup and join name based on them:

```
class RootController(TGController):
    @expose()
    def lookup(self, *args):
        name = '/'.join(args)
        return name
```